# Can I use a Mongo query to query a List of objects in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I would like to use a Mongo query to query a List of objects in c#.

I tried using FilterDefinition.Inject() as in the following example

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student {LastName="Omelchenko", Scores= new List<int> {97, 72, 81, 60}},
    new Student {LastName="O'Donnell", Scores= new List<int> {75, 84, 91, 39}},
    new Student {LastName="Mortensen", Scores= new List<int> {88, 94, 65, 85}},
    new Student {LastName="Garcia", Scores= new List<int> {97, 89, 85, 82}},
    new Student {LastName="Beebe", Scores= new List<int> {35, 72, 91, 70}}
};

FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = "{ LastName: Omelchenko }";
var filterQuery = students.Where(x => filter.Inject()).ToList();
```

but I get an exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LinqExtensions.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses.'
```

Is there any way to use a Mongo query to query a List of objects?

Comment: `Is there any way to use a Mongo query to query a List of objects?` - No unless they explicitly state it can be used for in memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot Igor, do you know there is a mongo query to linq query converter?

Comment: `do you know there is a mongo query to linq query converter` - this is a strange request since usually people want to get MQL request from a LINQ expression. I don't think that such thing exists, but if you only need to pass MQL expression to the driver for quering a server, not a random in memory data, then you can simply do stuff like: `coll.Find("{ randomCondition : 1 }")`

Comment: Thanks dododo, but I need to pass MQL expression to quering in memory data